# Oracle Editionable Package Changes

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle RDBMS 19c. Are there editioning views for packages? Is there a place where I can query them? I have made a change to a package that I believe is editionable, and now code referencing the package cannot find it. The error is:

ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called

In the case of a table, I know that I need to recreate the editioning view after changes as

```
create or replace editioning view MY_TABLE# as
  select * from MY_TABLE;
```

Do I need to do something similar when changing an editionable package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should find the source of the problem by checking statuses from dba_registry and/or from all_objects: Something like:

```sql
Select 
    COMP_ID,
    COMP_NAME,
    VERSION,
    STATUS,
    NAMESPACE,
    SCHEMA
From
    dba_registry;
```

... and/or ...

```sql
Select 
    * 
From 
    all_objects 
Where 
    OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE' And
    STATUS != 'VALID' and 
    OWNER = 'your_owner_name';
```

In most cases you should be able to address the problem and react to it. There is probably some of the packages with the status "INVALIDATED" and after a recompile the problem should be solved.